# Civ V won't let me destroy other cities

Tags: civilization-5

I'm at war with a country. I destroyed a city (it has 0 health) but it isn't letting me annex/create a puppet city out of it. It keeps saying that it's still owned by the Aztecs. Every turn it is able to harm my units and regains health.

If I attack the city after it's out of health, the attack animation plays but the red `-20 health` thing doesn't show, and their health bar doesn't go down.

The city I'm destroying isn't their capital, and I haven't attacked any other cities.

The civ I'm trying to destroy is [the Aztecs](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Aztec_(Civ5)). I have the brave new world DLC.

Comment: Are you attacking with ranged or melee? And are they land or water based?

Comment: Ranged, the caravel. Land based.

Comment: Have you attempted bringing a melee unit into the fight?

Comment: I don't have any. I'll make one though.

Comment: I've always had better luck at getting a city on my side if there is a melee unit putting it under siege.

Comment: You can't destroy (raze) capital cities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are unable to take a city via a normal ranged unit attack command. You will need a unit that can actually invade the city itself to gain control over it. [Some say you can use the move command if a cities health is low enough](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?95626-Archers-CAN-Take-Cities) but I haven't actually ever tried that. The best way I know of is to use a melee unit to invade the city after you have its health down low enough.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't playing "One City Challenge" are you?  Found in the advanced setup menu, this challenge only allows you to own one city the entire game.